# data dump from nseindia to excel

Tags: javascript, vba, jsp, excel

I need to dump the data from nseindia to the excel.please find the preview of nseindia in below link. From the webpage i need the **OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE and TotalBuyQty, TotalSellQty** values in the excel sheet, can anyone help me on the same. I tried normal webpage dump but it is not working.

"http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=WIPRO&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=30OCT2014&type=-&strike=-"

Answer (score 0):

Just use Excel to sort.

Thisis what happened when I recorded a sort in Excel.

```
Range("A1:A18").Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
    xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=True, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good guide to using the sort function without recording--you can trim it down if you're not using special methods.

sheet("Sheet1").range("Range1").sort key1:=Range("A2"), _
      order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646(v=office.15).aspx

If you're doing other manipulations to the field after that, you might want to use the AutoFilter as well.  Here's a helpful site for that if you're interested:
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba.htm

Comment: I also need to use a foreach for the webpage, i have the webpage links in my excel sheet. Can you please help me.